# Mazda mx5 mk1 1990 Cam oil seal leak B6 engine with 167.000km

Tags: engine, mazda, oil-leak, miata

Some history first, I had oil leaks in almost every top part of the engine. I changed, the cam cover gasket, cam oil seals and I put instant gasket on the cover edges for better sealing. That was sufficient for a while a month or so...Then, after I push the car a little bit more than usual above 4k rpm, it started leaking again. Another clue might be that the leak started after I change oil and oil filter, however I can't figure it out how those might connect.

So far, I've checked how much is the engine blowby. I checked all the solenoids for the PCV and breather valves. All of them look fine, also the engine doesn't burn oil. Soon I'm gonna do a compression test for extra evidence.

Ideally I would like to find what exactly is causing this leak before I change anything again.

Does anyone have any clue on what might be wrong here?

Thank you...

Comment: Is it leaking in all the same places it leaked previously? What is the mileage of the MX5? You said Mk1 ... but which year exactly? Are you sure you put the cam seals in correctly? No damage to them upon insertion? Completely square? No damage to where it rides on the cam? Any evidence of wear on the cam where the seal rides?

Comment: If you have access to an oil pressure gauge, I'd hook that up to see oil pressure at idle and 3500 rpm or so.  If the oil got very dirty at one point you may have a malfuntioning bypass in the pump assembly.  I found this nugget (I know your car is newer, but I doubt the pressures have changed much)  **"1990 Miata, the specified oil pump relief pressure is 50 - 64 psi, whereas the normal operating oil pressures are 28 - 43 psi at 1000 rpm and 43 - 57 psi at 3000 rpm. "**  Not an answer, but might eliminate a whole avenue of thought.  Along with that, is the filter fresh?

Comment: Paulster2: It does leak at the same places as before. The seals were fitted correctly and no damage to them or on the cam. When I removed the old seals where fitted firmly. 


SteveRacer: I used the pressure gauge on the dash to check if the pressure is correct and it does meet the specifications. But there is something that I'm not quite sure here. When I step on it, on warm engine, and pass the 4k rpm, the pressure can reach up to 6 kg/cm2, is that normal or indicates a malfunctioning oil bypass valve?

Comment: @Alimba   Heck yes, or at least I think so.  Gave this Yankee a bit of a headache, but [*I think*] 6 kgf/cm^2 works out to 85 psi.  Which is way too much, anywhere, anyhow.  But let's get somebody with more experience with that conversion to chime in before you panic.  If there was a metric to understand my understanding of metric, you'd understand that I don't understand metric...

Comment: @SteveRacer Yes, you are correct about the conversion of the units. So, there is one question remain, what is causing the pressure to keep rising after the 3k rpm? and how to fix it?

Comment: @SteveRacer Hi guys, some more data are coming up, I did a compression test, on the dry version of it I got a reading of 155 psi for all cylinders and the pressure build up there on the 3rd to 4th stroke. However when I did a wet test, I got, 155 psi for the first cylinder, no compression at all for the 2nd cylinder, 35 psi for the 3rd cylinder and 20 psi for the 4th cylinder. What that does it means? Piston rings? Head gasket or valves?

Comment: @Alimba  Frankly I don't believe those numbers.  That engine would barely run, if at all.

Comment: @SteveRacer well, I might did something wrong with the wet compression test, but still the dry was decent enough. 155psi on average with max difference of 2psi, besides the car doesn't burn oil or coolant. One more thing I've noticed is that when it's cold and rev hard it misfires, if I rev softly it is fine. All of the following parts are new spark leads, spark plugs, fuel filter, air cleaner. I don't know if that's any new clue to what really is happening with my motor.

Comment: @Alimba that sounds like excellent compression wet.  Still not convinced your high oil pressure is correct.  Sounds silly, but have you changed the oil filter again?  A defective oil filter might be the problem (crushed pleats, bad bypass, dead lizards ratio exceeded)  And you mentioned this started after an oil/filter change...  Cheap experiment: Throw another filter on.  Mazda, Mann or Wix; I'm certainly not unbiased.  No Fram/Allied Signal!  And there's always the PCV, if you have one.  Clogged crankcase ventilation plays havoc with oil pressure.  Another cheap experiment.

Comment: @SteveRacer Well, yes along with the oil change I change the oil filter too. As for the PCV I checked everything and seems to work. Is it possible the cam to be worn out and wobbles in high speeds? If yes, how can I test before reassemble anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened the engine again, and found out that it wasn't leaking from the camshaft this time, but from the crankshaft. That was the only thing that I didn't replace in the first place.

So, the advice here is, when you start replacing gaskets and seals of a system, replace all the involving gaskets and seals.

I hope that will help someone with similar issues.